# show active connection established when visit url

Tags: web

It's possibile know how and where connection are established when i visit specified URL?

I've to whitelist a specified url in my proxy but the site probabily use/open other connection blacklisted and i cannot visit this site.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dev tools in the browser might help aswell (F12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL might be a problem, but for domain-resolved listings, you may use `tcpdump`. E.g. for http- and https-requests, use

```
 tcpdump port 80 or port 443
```

`tcpdump` must run with root rights.